# FlutterSwitch - Unexpected Behaviour in AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my `AppBar()`, I wanna use `FlutterSwitch()` because I don't like the default Switch's style,

> so user can switch to dark mode (extra information!!)

When I use `FlutterSwitch()` in my `AppBar()`, **it's height gets enlarged to the size of the AppBar()**, like this...

[image]

However, when I use it in the body, it behaves normal and its default height doesn't get altered...

[image]

The code used to generate both the `FlutterSwitch` are same

```
FlutterSwitch(
  value: isSwitchOn,
  onToggle: (value) {
  setState(() {
  isSwitchOn = value;
 });
},)
```

Please help me resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: I've mailed him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlutterSwitch is built with `Container` widgets. You may place it in an `Align` widget, so it will occupy the only space it needs.

```dart
Align(
   child: FlutterSwitch(
       value: isSwitchOn,
       onToggle: (value) {
           setState(() {
               isSwitchOn = value;
           });
       },
   ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a better solution than just giving manual padding. Though padding worked, I wasn't satisfied.